# How to open Excel 2007 File from Password Protected Sharepoint 2007 site in R using RODBC or RCurl?

Tags: r, sharepoint-2007, excel-2007, rodbc, rcurl

I am interested in opening an Excel 2007 file in `R 2.11.1` using `RODBC`. The Excel file resides in the shared documents page of a MOSS2007 website. I currently download the `.xlsx` file to my hard drive and then import to `R` using the following code:

```
library(RODBC)
con<-odbcConnectExcel2007("C:/file location/file.xlsx")
data<-sqlFetch(con, "worksheet name")
close(con)
```

When I type in the web url for the document into the `odbcConnectExcel2007` connection, an error message pops up with:

```
ODBC Excel Driver Login Failed: Invalid internet Address.
```

followed by the following message in my R console:

```
 ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

Any insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE****

The site I am attempting to download from is password protected. I tried another method using the method 'getUrl' in the package `RCurl`:

`x = getURL("http://website.com/file.xlsx",  userpwd = "uname:pw")`

The error that I receive is:

`Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\006\0\b\0\0\0!\0dA»ï\001\0\0O\n\0\0\023\0Ò\001[Content_Types].xml ¢Î\001( \0\002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\`

I have no idea what this means. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using con <- odbcConnectExcel2007(url("http://sharepoint site/file.xlsx")) and the connection appeared to work, however when I attempted SQLFetch(), I get the error: table not found on channel.

Comment: The function `sqlTables(con)` will tell you which tables/sheets exist on the connection - take a look and see what actually is there.  It might be something as simple as a misspelled sheet name.  If you have special characters, spaces, or other oddities in your worksheet names, it sometimes helps to throw brackets around the worksheet name, thusly: "[worksheet name]".

Comment: @Matt Parker, thanks for the input, but `sqlTables(con)` returns 0 rows. I'm sure that it's not connecting to the actual file, however I'm not sure how to verify this. Thanks and let me know if you have any more suggestions!

Comment: Yes, sorry - if it were a problem with the worksheet name, you obviously would have had that same problem with the local copy.  What do you get from `odbcGetInfo(con)`?  Or from just typing `con` into the console?

Comment: @Matt Parker, thanks for your continued replies. Here are the responses to your questions. Let me know if they mean anything to you! Thanks! `odbcGetInfo(con) DBMS_Name "EXCEL" DBMS_Ver "12.00.0000" Driver_ODBC_Ver "03.51" Data_Source_Name "" Driver_Name 
"ACEODBC.DLL" Driver_Ver "Microsoft Office 2007 Access database engine" ODBC_Ver "03.52.0000" Server_Name "EXCEL"`

Comment: @Matt Parker, `> con RODBC Connection 1 Details:  case=nochange  DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\*username*\My Documents\3  DefaultDir=C:\Documents and Settings\*username*\My Documents  Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}  DriverId=1046  MaxBufferSize=2048 PageTimeout=5` **Idea:** Could it be that the SP site is password protected?

Comment: Your odbcGetInfo and con results look perfectly normal to me, so I think your question about the password protection is definitely relevant.  I don't know how to deal with that, unfortunately - you might check out the RCurl package, which I think ought to let you send the appropriate log-in requests to your SharePoint server.  That's way over my head, though.

Comment: You might want to try editing your question to fill in this new information - make the question about accessing a password-protected SharePoint file, rather than about RODBC.  That would bump the question back up to the top of the R questions and maybe garner more responses.

Comment: @Matt Parker, we are clearly on the same page. I was typing the update as you were typing the suggestion. Thanks for all your help! Hopefully some genius will know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions worked for me.

1. If you do not need to automate the script that pulls the data, you can [map a network drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d) pointing to the sharepoint folder from which you want to extract the Excel document.
2. If you need to automate a script to pull the Excel file every couple of minutes, I recommend sending your authentication credentials in a request that automatically saves the file to a local drive. From there you can read it into R for further data wrangling.

```
library("httr")   
library("openxlsx")
 
user <- <USERNAME>
password <- <PASSWORD>

url <- "https://sharepoint.company/file_to_obtain.xlsx"

httr::GET(url,
 authenticate(user, password, type="ntlm"),
 write_disk("C:/tempfile.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE))

df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("C:/tempfile.xlsx")
```

You can obtain the correct URL to the file by clicking on the sharepoint location and removing "?Web=1" after the file ending (xlsx, xlsb, xls,...). USERNAME and PASSWORD are usually windows credentials. It helps storing them in a key manager (such as:

```
library("keyring")
keyring::key_set_with_value(service = "Windows", username = "Key", password = <PASSWORD>)
```

and then authenticating via

```
authenticate(user, kreyring::key_get("Windows", "Key"), type="ntlm")
```

in some instances it may be sufficient to pass

```
authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm")
```

if only your Windows credentials are required and the code is running from your machine.